# Стилизация ссылок и родительсих блоков

Tags: html, css, валидация, style

Предположим, существует блок `<div class="item">` со ссылкой внутри `<a class="item__link">`:

```
<div class="item">    // .item {color: red; font-weight: 500;}
  <a class="item__link"> какой-либо текст </a>    // .item__link {color: red; font-weight: 500;}
</div>
```

С точки зрения ***правильности***, кому по итогу задавать стили (цвет, фонт-вейт/сайз/фэмэли и тому подобные стили) - блоку или ссылке?

На практике убедился, что такие бызовые вещи можно стилизовать и через блок и через ссылку одинаково, разницы на выходе не будет. Интересует - какой вариант **грамотнее**.

Comment: На мой взгляд семантика это про другое. "Семантическая вёрстка — подход к разметке, который опирается не на содержание сайта, а на смысловое предназначение каждого блока и логическую структуру документа". Поэтому, думаю, нет никакой разницы как вы стилизуете блоки с точки зрения семантики.

Comment: Значит неправильно поставил вопрос, сейчас исправлю

Comment: В этом примере вы используете БЭМ нотацию именования селекторов. Поэтому "правильность", о которой вы спрашиваете следует искать в этой методике. Возможно здесь подойдёт принцип единственной ответственности (англ. Single responsibility principle) в CSS по БЭМ означает, что каждая CSS-реализация должна иметь одну ответственность. Подробнее здесь https://ru.bem.info/methodology/css/#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8